# How to use the replace statement to replace a part of field value in 1000 rows

Tags: sql, replace

I want to replace the value in column account_no with value 'ACCxxx' to only 'xxx'

This is what I use now:

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account
     SET Value = REPLACE(value,'ACC','0')
    WHERE account_no LIKE ('ACC');
```

But it keeps giving an error

> Unknown column 'value' in field list.

Don't understand why.... Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  It seems *very* clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Value word you are using needs to be a column in your table, the error means it is not.

You said replace, so assuming you mean you want to update account_no, this should do that.  If not then you just replace the word Value in yours to whatever column name you want to update.

Also you said you want to remove ACC, but your replace is changing ACC to 0, so I removed that below as well so it just removes ACC.

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account 
SET account_no = REPLACE(account_no,'ACC','') 
WHERE account_no LIKE ('ACC');
```

Depending on SQL tecnology you may need to replace the Like line with this to use wild card for where statement.

```
WHERE account_no LIKE ('ACC%');
```

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks, the solution with second option worked. Strange, in the program I can see all data is without ACC, but in de database all data from that tabel all columns is gone... Still works as I see..

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account 
SET Value=REPLACE('ACCxxx',account_no) 
WHERE account_no LIKE '%ACC%'
```

Comment: I used the second option from Brad which worked the way I wanted. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This will not fix your problem, which is due to your using the wrong column

The code that you have written is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account
    SET Value = '0'
    WHERE account_no = 'ACC';
```

I suspect you want `value` to be `account_no`

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account
    SET account_no = '0'
    WHERE account_no = 'ACC';
```

This is the preferable way of writing it.  If you want to replace *all* occurrences of ACC with 0, then use:

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account
    SET account_no = REPLACE(account_no, 'ACC', '0')
    WHERE account_no LIKE '%ACC%';   -- note the wildcards;
```

If you want to remove ACC at the beginning and replace with `0`, use `stuff()`:

```
UPDATE dbo.dbo_account
    SET account_no = STUFF(account_no, 1, 3, '0')
    WHERE account_no LIKE 'ACC%';   -- note the wildcards;
```